# How to repeat a sequence of promises using ES6 API

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a sequence of promises that run one after the other.

```
var Sequence = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Timer,

    _sequence() {
        return this.reduce((promise,model)=>{
            return promise.then(()=>{
                return model.start(); // return a Promise
            });
        }, Promise.resolve());
    },

    start(count = 1) {
        // this sequence must be repeated for n times, where n is at least one
        return this._sequence();
    }
});
```

The model is a Timer. When I call *model.start()* it returns a promise that will fulfil when the timer expires.

How can I repeat that sequence so that I can do

```
var s1 = new Sequence([timer1, timer2, timer3]);
s1.start(2).then(function(){
   // the sequence was repeated 2 times
});
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recursively call yourself:

```
start(count = 1) {
    if (count <= 0)
         return Promise.resolve();
    else
         return this._sequence().then(() => this.start(count - 1));
}
```

Alternatively you can use the same approach as in your `sequence` method and write out the loop

```
start(count = 1) {
    var promise = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i=0; i<count; i++)
        promise = promise.then(() => this._sequence());
    return promise;
}
```